# Showing names in Excel cells does not work

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cells, vba

I use this function (this is Excel 2007, file type is *.xlsm)

```
Public Function CellName(oCell As Range) As Variant
Dim oName As Name
For Each oName In ThisWorkbook.names
  If oName.RefersToRange.Parent Is oCell.Parent Then
    If Not Intersect(oCell, oName.RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
       CellName = oName.Name
       Exit Function
    End If
  End If
Next
CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

to get the name of the cell.

It worked properly, but probably I removed some rows and it shows the error (so it loops until end, no names found). For every cell in the workbook. No cell having this in formula is ok.

I had this problem once and the problem was - I don't remember exactly - that there were names pointing to nothing. But now, as I open names Manager all names are ok, none put the same cell as any other.

I wrote a macro:

```
Sub names_delete()
  Dim oName As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 0
  For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.names.Count
   oName = ThisWorkbook.names(i).Name
   result = MsgBox(oName, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete name?")

   If (result = vbYes) Then
     ThisWorkbook.names(i).Delete
     Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

and the first name shown is "_xlfn.IFERROR". I can't delete it. This is not showing in Names Manager.

I googled but the only answer is that I could have used function that does not exist in my Excel, so other than 2007 Excel version, but that's not true, the 2007 was always used, however, I might have saved it once as 2003, I can't remember.

My question is - how to correct this function to have no error, or how to delete this "_xlfn.IFERROR" name or maybe the error is somewhere else.

As I've written, I already had the similar problem, but I solved it by repairing the erroneous name. Here all are correct (except "_xlfn.IFERROR").

**EDIT**

I can use names in formulas and there is no problem.

Comment: **I get the same** and as far as I can see it's an "Excel built-in name", you'll have to ring Bill Gates...;)

Comment: @glh On the web they say I used new not compatible function but the problem concerns name not a function

Comment: I've got 2010 and haven't used a non compatible formula... I think... Interesting!

Comment: Could it be this is occuring because a multisheet name has been modified, or its reference cells have been modified? Multisheet names will not appear in the name manager, ref [Working with Names](http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-us/files/333/880/AF010287486.mht).

Answer (score 1):

The name "_xlfn.IFERROR" is hidden, which means you cannot see it in Excel's native Name Manager.  You need to first unhide the name using a third-party solution like JPK's Name Manager or Macabacus' Name Scrubber.  Then, go back to Excel's native Name Manager and delete the name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem as well today.
From what I've read on the internet, Windows had first Excel 2007 without any Macro/Macro editor (scary but...). That's why for instance files with macro must have an independant extension as the one without.
Nevertheless, they finally react against protestation by including 2003 Macro system, which is not totally stable (formulars particularly).
Regarding this _xlfn.XXXXX hidden names, they are related to 2007/2010 new functions, not supported by 2003. It means you must not use the function with XXXXX name in the sheets if you want a play with names in macros.
When removed, you have to save, close and reopen the file to have the hidden name disappeared.

Hope it can help.

Denis

Answer (score -1):

> Option Explicit 
>  
>   Public Function CellName(oCell As Range) As Variant
>
> Dim oName As string 
>  
>   For Each oName In worksheet("sheet1").range("A1:Z65536")
>  
>      If oName.name = oCell.name
>
> Then
>        cellname = oName.name 
>  
>   'any other code you need  
>  
>     else
>
> ```
>  exit function
> ```
>
> end if
>
> Next End Function

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. I changed `worksheet("sheet1")` to `ActiveWorkbook` but it does not solve the problem.